# Can't run Tkinter on Heroku

Tags: python-2.7, heroku, tkinter

I am using Python 2.7, and I can't get Tkinter to run once it's pushed to Heroku. It works fine locally. Specifically, I am getting the following error:

```
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python main.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5000`
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
app[web.1]:   File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
app[web.1]:     from tools.samplewin import samplewin
app[web.1]:     from Tkinter import Tk, Text, WORD, DISABLED, NORMAL, BooleanVar, StringVar
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 39, in <module>
app[web.1]:     import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
app[web.1]:   File "/app/tools/samplewin.py", line 6, in <module>
app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named _tkinter
```

It seems Tcl/Tk needs to be installed, based on Step 1 of **Checking your Tkinter support** on the [wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter). Since the cedar-14 stack for the Heroku app is based on Ubuntu, I added the apt buildpack (https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt) to my app as the first buildpack to be executed, with tk-dev as the only package in the Aptfile.

When I push to Heroku, the tk, tk8.6, tcl, tcl8.6 (and -dev versions of each) packages are all installed, but I end up with the same error when I access the app.

I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: are you trying to serve tkinter applications via the web? That's not going to work.

Comment: new Ubuntu use Python 3 without Tkinter and you have to install `apt install python3-tk`. Probably Python 2 needs to install `python-tk` too. But it will be display only on local monitor - it means connected to Heroku machine. You can try to use some Remote Desktop programs to see it but most servers use Linux without X Windows so they can't display any window - including Tkinter window - even on monitor connected to Heroku machine.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to have some Tkinter apps available for my use over the web. I see now why that wouldn't work. Thank you.